# java regex to match variable

Tags: java, regex

I have the name of a java variable in a string. I want to replace it with the letter x. How can I do this java, and make sure that other words in the string are not replaced ?

For example, say my variable is `res`, and my string is "`res = res + pres + resd + _res`. I want the string to become `x = x + pres + resd + _res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word boundary to only capture whole words:

```
String s = "res = res + pres + resd + _res";
String var = "res";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\b" + var + "\\b", "x"));
```

outputs `x = x + pres + resd + _res`

Comment: I really want any correct way to create a variable (as allowed by the language itself) to be taken into account. I added _res in my original post to reflect this example. "res=res+pres" should also work, even though there are no spaces

Comment: @Car981 The code I propose will work with `_res` or `res=res+pres` too.

Comment: Okay, will it also work with dollar signs, numbers, and basically anything that is given here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming ?

Comment: @Car981 Yes it should - note that the list of valid characters provided in that link is far from exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\b` metacharacter to match a word boundary.  (Bear in mind you'll need to use doule backslashes to escape this in Java.)

So you can do something like the following:

```
final String searchVar = "res";
final String replacement = "x";
final String in = "res = res + pres + resd + _res";

final String result = in.replaceAll("\\b" + searchVar + "\\b", replacement);
System.out.println(result);
// prints "x = x + pres + resd + _res"
```